# using nested while loops

Tags: javascript, while-loop

Trying to solve a problem using nested while loops, but having trouble grasping how to approach the problem, here is the problem:

Exercise: n numbers are coming to a number party. Introduce them each to all the guests as they arrive. You should end up with output looking something like this one for n = 5:

```
  "welcome 1"
  "welcome 2, meet 1"
  "welcome 3, meet 1 and 2"
  "welcome 4, meet 1, 2 and 3"
  "welcome 5, meet 1, 2, 3 and 4"
```

An example of nested While Loops:

```
var i = 0, j, n = 5

while ( i < n ) {
  j = 0 // What happens 

     while ( j < n ) {
     console.log("i is", i, "and j is", j)
     j++   }   i++

}
```

Comment: Build a function to print "welcome n". Build another one to print "meet 1". Build another to print 2, 3, ..., n - 2. Build another to print and n - 1. Test each function as you go. Put them all together. Job done!

Comment: @milez ... so, what if the problem is homework? ... would that be a problem?

Comment: `while ( j < i ) ` might help :P

Comment: @OleSauffaus I thought there was a tag for it but seems like its deprecated

Comment: @OleSauffaus, its not a problem because its homework per se, its a problem because its clear the OP hasnt even put minimal effort or showed us what he has tried so far. SO is not a free coding service

Comment: @AmmaeCSE & milez ... then point out, that the question is lacking in effort ... not that it is bad to ask about homework-assignments.

Comment: I hadn't come up with anything worth while, hence why I posted here. It's not home work either, it's a practice exercise and nothing more. Just curious because I couldn't see how this could be done. Also, i didn't see how this could be done with the specification IE having the lines produced and formatted like the example answer through console.log.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

solution with FOR

```
var N=10; // 10 numbers

for(var i=0; i<N; i++){

  console.log("Welcome " + (i+1) + "");
  if(i > 0) {
    console.log(", meet");

    for(var j=0; j<i; j++){
      if(j > 0){
        if(j == i-1){
          console.log(" and" );
        }else{
          console.log(" ," );
        }
      }
      console.log(" " + (j+1));
    }
  }
  console.log("\n" );
}
```

solution with WHILE

```
var i=0;
while(i<N){

  console.log("Welcome " + (i+1) + "");
  if(i > 0) {
    console.log(", meet");

    var j=0;
    while(j<i){
      if(j > 0){
        if(j == i-1){
          console.log(" and" );
        }else{
          console.log(" ," );
        }
      }
      console.log(" " + (j+1));
      j++
    }
  }
  console.log("\n" );
  i++;
}
```

Comment: This ain't a java question.

Comment: woooops, just a second

Comment: Might want to place that `j++` inside the while or it will run for quite a while. Pun intended.

Comment: you are right, thanks